# Automapper ProjectTo not working with ForPath Members

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to implement a more elegant call in my repository by using `.ProjectTo<>` in Automapper instead of getting an IEnumerable and then mapping those results to the Dto. When I switched to this method my mapping no longer works for anything mapped using `.ForPath()`.

Mapping:

```
//Context.Account -> Account
configuration.CreateMap<Context.Account, Account>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest.BillingAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => new Address(source.BillingStreet, source.BillingCity, source.BillingState, source.BillingPostalCode, source.BillingCountry)))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.ShippingAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => new Address(source.ShippingStreet, source.ShippingCity, source.ShippingState, source.ShippingPostalCode, source.ShippingCountry)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Events, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingStreet, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.BillingAddress.Street))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingCity, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.BillingAddress.City))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingState, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.BillingAddress.State))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingPostalCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.BillingAddress.PostalCode))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingCountry, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.BillingAddress.Country))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingStreet, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ShippingAddress.Street))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingCity, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ShippingAddress.City))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingState, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ShippingAddress.State))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingPostalCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ShippingAddress.PostalCode))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingCountry, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ShippingAddress.Country));
```

Here is the code in my repository:

BEFORE (**Address being populated**):

```
List<Account> accounts;

IQueryable<Context.Account> iqueryable = _dbContext.Set<Context.Account>();

if (spec != null)
{
    var filter = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Context.Account, bool>>>(spec.FilterCriteria);
    iqueryable = iqueryable.Where(filter);

    if (spec is Paging<Account> paging)
    {
        var orderByExpression = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Context.Account, object>>>(paging.OrderBy);
        iqueryable = iqueryable.OrderBy(orderByExpression).Take(paging.Take).Skip(paging.Skip);
    }
}

accounts = iqueryable
   .ToList()
   .Select(x => Mapper.Map<Account>(x))
   .ToList();

return accounts;
```

AFTER (**Address not being populated**):

```
IQueryable<Account> iqueryable = _dbContext.Set<Context.Account>()
                .ProjectTo<Account>();

if (spec != null)
{
   if (spec is Paging<Account> paging)
   {
      iqueryable = paging.Prepare(iqueryable);
   }
   else
   {
      iqueryable = iqueryable.Where(spec.FilterCriteria);
   }
}
return iqueryable.ToList();
```

Comment: Use ForMember instead.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu that doesn't work for me. I get the error 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'

Comment: Well yes, but that's not because of ForMember. It because your mapping cannot work with ProjectTo.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu how would you suggest fixing the mapping to work with that? I had issues with this before and changing it from ForMember to ForPath solved the mapping issue in the past.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: .New Account(){
    Id = $dto.Id,
    Name = $dto.Name,
    OwnerId = $dto.OwnerId,
    ParentId = $dto.ParentId,
    Phone = $dto.Phone,
    AlternatePhone = $dto.AlternatePhone,
    BillingAddress = .New Address(
        $dto.BillingStreet,
        $dto.BillingCity,
        $dto.BillingState,
        $dto.BillingPostalCode,
        $dto.BillingCountry),
    ShippingAddress = .New Address(
        $dto.ShippingStreet,
        $dto.ShippingCity,
        $dto.ShippingState,
        $dto.ShippingPostalCode,
        $dto.ShippingCountry)
}

Comment: And that's exactly what the error says. You'll have to use a default constructor or an initializer.